# Bolt size for Velbon tilt head?

Tags: tripod, camera

i recently purchased a used Velbon CX 470 tripod
when i got it home i found that it is missing the bolt/screw that holds the top piece to the main body (and allows the camera to be rotated, rolled, sideways).
[image: Part in question circled here:]

does anyone know the name of this part/bolt/screw
where might i find a replacement?
Can i just get a bolt from the hardware store - if so what length, thread count/pitch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I found some answers at my local hardware store.
A 60mm M6 bolt fits perfectly.

Comment: Great! Thanks for coming back and following up with an answer. You can also accept your own answer, if it's the most useful one for you. (There's no problem with asking, answering, and accepting your own question)

Comment: For easier turning, you could insert a M6 wingnut on the bolt and glue it into place, tightened against the nut head.

Answer (score 1):

Unless Velbon sells the part, the only options are to find a donor tripod with the part you need or fabricate something yourself.

The threads are almost certainly a common size, probably metric unless they are 1/4-20 or 3/8”. So you could start fabrication with threaded rod once you know the size.

On the other hand, the simplest thing might be to buy a tripod that isn’t broken. With patience, you can probably find one of similar build quality for very little money. Or a good used tripod from a company like Bogen Manfrotto for less than $100.

Comment: Not really. The simplest would be, if not properly measured and bought, to utilize a glue or a duct tape, which might even work just fine if OP had L bracket or two mounting plates (2-5GBP/piece ebay) for the joint. The Velbon tripod itself costs around 40 EUR for a brand new one (I have one myself) and a way less for the used one. No need to spend more money on the solution which judging by the brand and by that it's used is exactly the OP's case. Otherwise OP would just buy a new system in the local photo store.

Comment: @PeterBadida Better availability of spare parts is why I suggested companies like Bogen Manfrotto.

Comment: Ah, I needed to look it up (unknown vendor for me)! In that case it makes sense when [even the vendor itself](https://www.manfrotto.com/us-en/customer-service/spare-parts/) sells the spares and also with sites such [this one](https://www.manfrottospares.com). Depending on the country, it might be way better to go with similar vendor than just buy the cheapest and don't have a support. Trade offs. :) Have an upvote!